# Dynamic ngModel in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am trying to create dynamic ngModel within ngFor, I have an object array of the phone numbers which I need to bind with the form element & user can update that details, below is my code:

```
phoneNumber = [{
    'type': 'mobile', 
    'number': '1234567', 
    'label': 'Personal'
}, {
    'type': 'landline', 
    'number': '64332222', 
    'label': 'Work'
}];

<div class="form-field-block" *ngFor="let phone of phoneNumber; let i = index ">
    <div class="form-group>
        <select name="phoneLabel" class="custom-select form-control-sm" [(ngModel)]="phone.label">
            <option value="Personal">Personal</option>
            <option value="Home">Home</option>
            <option value="Work">Work</option>
        </select>
        <select name="phoneFor" class="custom-select form-control-sm" [(ngModel)]="phone.type">
            <option value="mobile">Mobile</option>
            <option value="landline">Landline</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" placeholder="Phone Number" [(ngModel)]="phone.number">
    </div>
</div>
```

So here `[(ngModel)]="phone.label"` is not binding properly, values are not getting updated in the object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NgValue` directive instead of value when you're working with select and `NgModel` directive, and you should also add `[ngModelOptions]="{ standalone : true }"` to your inputs to prevent them being added to same `FormGroup` instance if you are using forms:

```
<select name="phoneLabel" class="custom-select form-control-sm" [(ngModel)]="phone.label" [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone : true }">
    <option [ngValue]="'Personal'">Personal</option>
    <option [ngValue]="'Home'">Home</option>
    <option [ngValue]="'Work'">Work</option>
</select>
<select name="phoneFor" class="custom-select form-control-sm" [(ngModel)]="phone.type" [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone : true }">
    <option [ngValue]="'mobile'">Mobile</option>
    <option [ngValue]="'landline'">Landline</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" placeholder="Phone Number" [(ngModel)]="phone.number" [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone : true }">
```